# Does every Grundfos circulator pump need a bypass valve?

Tags: plumbing

We recently moved into a house that was built in 2018. There's a 98420222 Grundfos comfort PM installed right over the water heater. Unfortunately, it doesn't work and we have to wait 2-3 minutes for hot water in our bathroom.

There's no bypass valve anywhere in the house. Does this pump require a bypass valve? I can't find a conclusive answer from their manuals.

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean by "bypass valve" here.  But is the Grundfos pump working?  You should be able to feel it vibrating slightly and probably hear it.

Comment: Are you looking for valve(s) to isolate the pump so you can remove it from the line & replace it?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, a (missing or installed) bypass valve is not the cause for this problem.

If that pump is really the warm water circulation pump, sometimes users permanently switch off that pump in order to reduce the huge losses which are caused by recirculation.

But the big delay points to another possibility: There should be a timer function in the heating system' s control menu to switch on that pump only 2 or 3 times per day for 30 minutes according to the needs.

That time schedule could be unsuited, e.g. if the former owner worked on night or moon shifts.

To minimize losses, all warm water lines should be insulated as much as possible, especially warm water recirculation lines.

If the waiting time is 2 to 3 minutes, those lines would be very long and would lose much energy to the walls, if the insulation is insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a dedicated return line? If so, you don't need a valve to send cooled hot water back via the cold water pipes, but you probably still want a check valve in that line to prevent pulling that cooled water out the far end faucets, rather than hot water from the hot pipes.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to grundfos and they told me two things:

- this pump model is only for homes with a return valve to send cooled water back to the hot water heater for recirculating.
- to test if it's working, unplug it for several hours, so that it forgets the previous homeowners schedule. Then plug it back in and set the recirculating mode to 100% and see what it does. I did this and heard a very faint hum that I was reluctant to attribute to the grundfos pump, since it's in a utility closet with HVAC and other stuff. A few minutes later, every faucet in the house started getting hot water within 6 or 7 seconds of turning on the tap.

So it works, and we have a hidden return line inside the walls somewhere. Only the cold water main appears to go into the cold input on the water heater.

Now I have to figure out how to make this less wasteful since we have a gas water heater and are home constantly with little kids turning on water often.

Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 0):

The thermal valve should be installed under one of your faucets.  It shouldn't be hidden in a wall. They go bad after several years and need to be replaced. I'm getting ready to replace mine.

The idea is you place it under the farthest faucet from the water heater.  I placed a second one under my main bathroom as well even though it not far, because that line comes up near an outside wall in an uninsulated crawlspace.  We had issues with that line freezing when outside temps got around zero F. So I don't use the time in the winter. My pump is a Watts Premier and has a timer on it.  So you can set times for it to run.  If yours doesn't you should be able to find a smart timer for the outlet it plugs into.  We really like ours.